# Bipartite graphs, degrees and neighbors

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (X \cup Y, E)$ be a bipartite graph with no isolated vertices and let $S \subseteq X$. Suppose $|S| = |N(S)|$ (neighboors of $S$) and that $\forall \{x,y\} \in E$, where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, $\deg(x) \ge \deg(y)$.

It is not obvious to me why $\sum_{x\in S}{\deg(x)} \ge \sum_{y\in N(S)}{\deg(y)}$. It seems obvious for my colleagues but they can't explain it to me. Can anyone provide a formal proof or clear intuition ?

Comment: I changed deg to \deg.  This not only prevents italicization but also affects format in expressions like $a\deg b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You probably mean $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ in the assumption on degrees ?

Comment: I mean that for any edge (going from $X$ to $Y$ as bipartite graph) $e = \{x,y\}$ with $x$ endpoint of $e$ in $X$ and $y$ endpoint of $e$ in $Y$ then $\deg(x) \ge \deg(y)$.

Comment: Ok, you should say it clearly because similarity of letters is not enough... Anyway the result seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stated result is wrong, at least in its current form form. Consider for instance $S=\{x_1,x_2\}$, $X=S\cup\{x_3\}$, $Y=\{y_1,y_2\}$ and edges $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_1,y_2)$ $(x_3,y_1)$, $(x_3,y_2)$.
Remark that $x_2$ is isolated.

Then all assumptions are verified, but the conclusion is not: sum of degrees is $2$ in $S$ and $4$ in $N(S)$.

Comment: Oups, forgot no isolated vertex, sorry

Comment: then it is true, because to each $x\in S$ you can map a $y_x$ in $N(S)$ connected to it in a bijective way. This is showed by induction. Then $\sum \deg(x)\geq \sum \deg(y_x)$.

Comment: ok, so you do it by induction on the size of $|S|$ with a base case of size 1 and on the induction step, you make the matching $(x_{n+1}, y_k)$ where $y_k$ is adjacent to $x_{n+1}$ and conclude from $n$ remaining vertices of both sides.

Comment: yes, you have to show that there is always a $y_k$ which has not be chosen before. Another solution is to use the following theorem which directly gives you the wanted result: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig's_theorem_(graph_theory)